# use class based on a property value

Tags: angular, angular6

`[ngClass]` is not working when I try to select Css class based on a property of class.

**i.e.**

```html
[ngClass]="{'alert alert-danger': employeeForm.get('fullname').errors && (employeeForm.get('fullname').touched || employeeForm.get('fullname').dirty) }"
```

Above code works in `*ngIf` but not in `[ngClass]` .

I am following a youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPuXl1DS1vU&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWNJaDgh0mfae_9xoQ4E_Zj&index=9)

```js
export class CreateEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  employeeForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeForm = this.fb.group({
      fullname: ['', Validators.required ],
      email: [''],

      skills : this.fb.group({
        skillName: [''],
        experience: [''],
        proficiency: ['beginner']
      })
    });
  }

  onLoadDataClick(): void {
    this.employeeForm.setValue({
      fullname: 'Jamshaid Tariq',
      email: 'jamshaid055@yahoo.com',
      skills: {
        skillName: 'C#',
        experience: 1,
        proficiency: 'beginner'
      }
    });
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log(this.employeeForm.value);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to make sure it's a boolean by adding !!:

```
[ngClass]="{'alert alert-danger': !!(employeeForm.get('fullname').errors && (employeeForm.get('fullname').touched || employeeForm.get('fullname').dirty)) }"
```

I took your code and this works. I only added one ! to test
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fquu8t

Comment: This thing worked... thanks but why angular is not treating it as condition, i have used `&&` , it must turn it into true false..?

Comment: and one more thing, can i do `employeeForm.get('fullname').errors.required`?, i have tried it i get error `Cannot read property 'required'. ` but in tutorial i have already linked with my question, he does it without any error

Comment: oky so now i know, i can `errors` returns an array, i can use `employeeForm.get('fullname').errors['required']` instead of `employeeForm.get('fullname').errors.required`

Comment: Thanks for sharing the actual solution. I was just focused on how to show the class depending on a condition.